# Migration from svn to git: How do I create .gitignore files for a big repository with an unstable connection?

Tags: svn, git, github, gitignore

I've just migrated a big open source project from subversion to git.

I am trying to do a `git svn create-ignore`, but after about 30 minutes it fails because the svn server connection sometimes fails:

> RA layer request failed: PROPFIND of
>   '...': could not connect to server
>   (...).

Now, the problem is, that if I do `git svn create-ignore` again, it restarts completely over (unlike `git svn fetch` which continues from where it broke). So it never gets past about 25% of the project. Is this fixable?

Comment: Uhm... why is the connection **that** bad?

Comment: Which project? Most of the gnu ones, say, offer an rsync of the repository so you could do the whole thing locally?

Comment: The connection isn't too bad as much as the project's too huge. It looks like the "git svn create-ignore" is making a separate connection for every single file. Sometimes it fails on file 500, sometimes on file 5000 I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

- First create a local mirror of the entire SVN repository with `svnsync` as described [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt).
- Now edit the URL in your [svn-remote] section in `.git/config` to point to your local mirror (you can use a `file:///` URL).
- Try `git svn create-ignore` again.
- Change your `.git/config` back to point to the real repository again.

Creating the local mirror will take a lot of time, bandwidth and disk space, but at least you can resume it if it is interrupted halfway.

Comment: Good idea. Except that I couldn't creating a local mirror because loading the svn dump doesn't load (probably because there's a corruption in the SVN history). Bad luck never strikes alone :)

Comment: @Geoffrey: I'm confused - `svnsync` does not use a svn dump. It gets it information like any other SVN client. Also, the fact that you used  an SVN dump seems to suggest that you have administrative access to the repository. In that case you can just copy the entire repository folder, a dump/load cycle is not necessary.

Comment: Good point, I confused svnsync with svnadmin dump and load. Since I was under a deadline I did the svn ignores manually, just hope I didn't miss any :/